# TortoiseHG fails to import patch

Tags: mercurial, patch, tortoisehg

I have a patch file here in unified diff format I'd like to import. But when I do it in the workbench via Repository -> Import, it just closes the window and it seems that nothing happened. What could go wrong here?

Comment: What does the TortoiseHg log window show?  Have you tried importing the patch on the command line?  (Try `hg help import`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you importing the patch on top of the correct previous revision? Patch contains only the changeset and it to work properly you need all its previous changesets applied on your branch before hand.